# AWS EventBridge Monitoring ECR - Do you need to also configure CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I cannot seem to find this answer anywhere and the docs are quite confusing... for ECR actions in AWS do you need to explicitly configure any CloudFormation components or any other mechanisms for events to be captured in AWS EventBridge?

I have scans enabled continuous which I can verify in the UI as well as auditing such as pulls etc. For debugging, my Event Pattern right now is super simple:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "CloudFormation template for EventBridge rule 'aws-ecr-scans-to-slack'",
  "Resources": {
    "EventRule0": {
      "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
      "Properties": {
        "Description": "",
        "EventBusName": "default",
        "EventPattern": {
          "source": ["aws.ecr"]
        },
        "Name": "aws-ecr-scans-to-slack",
        "State": "ENABLED",
        "Targets": [{
          "Id": "<ID>",
          "Arn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:<AWS-Account-ID>:ECR-Container-Scanning-EventBridge-to-AWSChatbot"
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I go to the "Monitoring" tab of the EventBridge in question and see zero results.. Any ideas? Please help, hoping this should be an easy one!

[This AWS article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr-eventbridge.html) seems to imply that ECR events are auto-sent to EventBridge..

[This article](https://www.element7.io/2021/03/aws-chatbot-to-the-rescue-never-miss-an-aws-security-alert/) uses CloudFormation which may be legacy(?)

TYIA! (Y)

Answer (score 0):

CloudFormation is just a service for creating other AWS resources. Once CloudFormation creates those other resources, they exist without CloudFormation's involvement. The resources CloudFormation creates are not different in any way from the resources you create through the AWS web console, the AWS SDK, the AWS CLI tool, etc. Behind the scenes CloudFormation is just using the AWS API to create resources for you, just like all those other tools do.

So no, you do not need to use CloudFormation in order to make EventBridge events work.

Are you sure you have created your EventBridge event filter on the default Event Bus? Only the default Event Bus receives events from other AWS services.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply and assistance! Yes, confirming and I updated the description with the "CloudFormation Template" when viewing the current config of my EventBridge, if that helps and you see any noticable errors?

Do you also know if a CloudTrail Log Group and Stream is mandatory for this? I noticed these events are also empty and seems related.. I.E "The dashboard below shows metrics for the rule. View the metrics in CloudWatch"

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your rule, and according to this you shouldn't need to do anything else: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/eventbridge-support-in-amazon-elastic-container-registry/

Comment: OK so I now have got a little further.
I tested a custom Event Bridge and custom Email-based SNS and can confirm I am getting emails successfully.
Under my Event Bridge "Monitoring" for SNS->Slack via AWS ChatOps I see counts against "Triggered Rules" .... meaning my problem is the slack-based SNS and the AWS Chatbot to Slack config?

Do you know how I tshoot the SNS notification and AWS ChatBot end?